# Ruby on Rails 5 AREL Dynamic SELECT/ORDER values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I am having trouble finding docs on the Rails way of doing something like:

```
email = "abc@yahoo.com"
results = Contact.select(:id, :email, "levenshtein(email, '#{email}',1,1,6) AS confidence").order("levenshtein(email, '#{email}',1,1,6)")
```

I know with where clause we can use ? instead of using #{email}, but having trouble getting that to work with SELECT and ORDER.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The ? is mostly to bind values and avoid asking the database with unexpected values. In the case of a SELECT statement, it'd add no value doing so, unless of course, you have a subquery, but that's kind of difficult looking at your code and using AR for it. You could just leave it like that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was bringing this up Brakeman was complaining about it saying it could be prone to injection. I realize it may have a false positive but was just seeing if there was an easy solution to it.

Comment: As I [see](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/972), it's some old false-positive. You could somehow ignore the warning if Brakeman allows doing so.

Comment: You could replace `"levenshtein(email, '#{email}',1,1,6)"` with `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("levenshtein",[Arel.sql("email"),Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(email),1,1,6])` which will result in an identical query and should alleviate the warning.